# How to check if a columns value was explicitly specified in a PL/SQL BEFORE UPDATE trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Is there a way to tell which columns were explicitly updated in a PL/SQL `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger?

For example: I want to set `:new.last_modified_by := USER` only if the `UPDATE` statement did not explicitly specify a value for this column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `UPDATING` function:

```
if updating('LAST_MODIFIED_BY') then 
...
end if;
```

More details are in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#BCFIDDBB

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: I thought about the `IS NULL` as well. That would be "true" for an `update foo set last_modified_by = null` as well. Depends on the OP if that should be considered "explicitely stating a value" or not

Comment: oh - I love this.  Thanks.